# ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

Tags: ansible

I was asked to create a `simpefile.txt` if does not exist in the directory
so I created a directory first using Adhoc command then using playbook I created this:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: check for file
      stat: path=/home/user/test/simplefile.txt
      register: stat_result

    - name: copy file
      file: path=/home/user/test/simplefile.txt state=touch
      when: not stat_result.stat.exists
```

But getting an error:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>
The error appears to be in '/projects/challenge/fresco_when/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: all
  ^ here
```

Comment: Are these tasks from an Ansible role?

Comment: Based on the filename `tasks/when.yml` it seems you have duplicated the **playbook** format inside your **tasks** list; files inside the `tasks` directory should be `list[dict]` only, that is just a top-level `- debug: msg=hello` and not anything about `- hosts`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone: I had the same error message in a slightly different case than the OP. I wrote by mistake

```yaml
- name: ...
  ansible.builtin.block:
  - ...
  - ...
```

But `block` is a primitive, not a module. It should be instead

```yaml
- name: ...
  block:
  - ...
  - ...
```

The error message was *rather* confusing.